# jquery simple slider not return again

Tags: jquery

this slider work properly till the last child and it should return again to first child but it did not that, it reached to last and faded out and stop 
and number of children is 5 , why does not it return again???

```
/* Start Auto Slider Code*/
       (function autoSlider(){
            $('.sliderr .active').each(function(){
                if(!$('this').is(':last-child')){
                    $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
                   $(this).removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').fadeIn();
                        autoSlider();      
                        });
                }
                else{
                    $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                        $('.sliderr div').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn();
                        autoSlider(); 
                        }); 
                }
                });
        }());
     /* End Auto Slider Code*/
```